Passing an event to externall source
I'm working on a lib for PS5 DualSense controller, based on dualsense_controller.
I want to import it in my python program and somehow pass event's from this lib.
from time import sleep
from dualsense_controller import DualSenseController

class DS5:
    def __init__(self, controller_nb=0, debug = False):
        '''
        '''
        # list availabe devices and throw exception when tzhere is no device detected
        device_infos = DualSenseController.enumerate_devices()
        if len(device_infos) < 1:
            raise Exception('No DualSense Controller available.')

        # flag, which keeps program alive
        self.is_running = True
        self.debug = debug

        self.controller = DualSenseController(device_index_or_device_info=device_infos[controller_nb])
        self.register_callbacks()
        # enable/connect the device
        self.controller.activate()

    def register_callbacks(self):
        # register the button callbacks
        self.controller.btn_cross.on_down(self.on_cross_btn_pressed)
        self.controller.btn_cross.on_up(self.on_cross_btn_released)

        # register the error callback
        self.controller.on_error(self.on_error)

    # callback, when cross button is pressed, which enables rumble
    def on_cross_btn_pressed(self):
        if self.debug == True:
            print('cross button pressed')

    # callback, when cross button is released, which disables rumble
    def on_cross_btn_released(self):
        if self.debug == True:      
            print('cross button released')

    def __exit__(self):
        self.controller.deactivate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ds5 = DS5(debug=True)
    while Ds5.is_running:
        sleep(0.001)

So when for example button is pressed, it's going to execute some method in that program.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

I'm guessing that you want to register callbacks for other events, for that I suggest looking at the documentation of the dualsense_contoller lib

Actually, that documentation is quite bad, better take a look at the example.
